# In Shovel Knight what's special about the sparkling pits?

Tags: shovel-knight

I see these pits on a bunch of level that sparkle, and I've jumped down them a few times and always die. There has to be something special about them or else they wouldn't sparkle. Any tips on those? Feel like I'm near the end of the game and have just left a bunch of treasure.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can buy a fishing rod in the first town; use it like any other item while facing a sparkling pit to enter a basic fishing minigame like the kind in Animal Crossing or what have you - use the item again when an exclamation mark appears above Shovel Knight's head to catch a fish.

These fish are either worth money, or will refill an empty ichor chalice.

Comment: Thanks, never even got the fishing rod, must have missed that entirely. Will try it out!